# Use Set in SOSL queries

Tags: sosl, set

Currently I am using SOQL query in apex class:

`for(Account acc: [Select FirstName,LastName,Territory_vod__c,NPI_vod__c from Account where Name In:accountSet ]){`

`accountSet` is set having list of names.
Due to requirements,I need to replace this query with SOSL query with something like this:

`FIND :accountSet IN NAME FIELDS Returning account(id)`

but I am not able to iterate over accountSet. What could be the workarounds to use set in SOSL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis for search in your SOSL. 
Refer [FIND {SearchQuery}](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm) document.

Quote from documentation:

> **( )**- Use parentheses around search terms with logical operators to group
>   search terms. For example, you can search for: ("Bob" and "Jones") OR
>   ("Sally" and "Smith")—searches for either Bob Jones or Sally Smith.
>   ("Bob") and ("Jones" OR "Thomas") and Sally Smith—searches for
>   documents that contain Bob Jones and Sally Smith or Bob Thomas and
>   Sally Smith.

An example here:

```
String searchTerms = '("keyWord 1") OR ("keyWord 2")';
System.debug([FIND :searchTerms RETURNING Account(Name, Rating, BillingState)]);
```

So, You have to enclose each tearm inside a parenthesis and use `AND`/`OR` operator.